# Tridion Sites 9.6 Core Service.REST for workflow (yet)?

Tags: core-service, sites-9.6

Tridion Sites 9.6 introduces the public, supported Core Service.REST API for interacting with the Content Manager.

I understand expected use cases for the API include Content Manager-side programmatic interactions such as reporting, (non-Event System) automation, or connections with other systems.

The API also exposes External Content Library (ECL) and Translation Manager (TM) IDs transparently, alongside core Content Manager items. So ECL or TM type reports and integrations are easier.

**But would it be possible or expected to use Core Service.REST for things like Workflow automation** (for Sites 9.6)?

*Are there other use cases you'd recommend for customers adopting Sites 9.6 or say, delta training. ;-)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Core Service REST API in Tridion Sites 9.6 provides limited workflow support (just enough to serve Experience Space UI, which also provides limited workflow support in 9.6).

More extensive workflow support is on the backlog for the release after 9.6.